# How does formation of sharp shadows relate to rectilinear propagation of light

Tags: visible-light

So in my physics book, it is given that light travels in a straight line and this can be concluded as light casts a *sharp* shadow when it is obstructed by an object.

Now I don't understand how a shadow being sharp relates to the rectilinear propagation of light. Can somebody please explain this to me?

Also, even if this is true, then aren't shadows hazy too?

Answer (score 1):

Your book assumes a point source of light. In reality light sources are extended objects; the sun for example has about a half degree apparent width, so shadows cast in sunlight are fuzzy-edged. A sharper shadow can be cast with something like a single LED on the far side of a large room, but because typical LEDs are a few millimeters wide, the shadow will still be fuzzy in close inspection.

Another thing to account for in real environments is reflection from other nearby objects. If even a point source light reflects off, say, a large wall, the reflected light from the wall will cast a hazy shadow.

Comment: Alright, but I still don't get how even a point source making a sharp shadow proves that light travels in straight lines...

Comment: Because if the light was bending and curving every which way as it traveled, some of it would fall behind the object and the shadow would not be sharp.